# Is there any way to observe change in Database table through Hibernate?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, orm

In my application, I am storing a small table containing 50 records in a singleton class because the data in this table hardly changes - e.g. the list of countries.

Although, the concept is not good, I have to continue with it right now. Is there any solution in Hibernate which observe change in the table and on change, invoke a method of a class to update the variable.

Comment: Everybody keeps repeating the chant about Singletons being evil, but this mainly goes for old fashioned (private constructor + getInstance method) Singleton implementations, their main drawbacks being hard to unit test and not robust in multi-threaded or clustered environments. However, Spring offers a perfectly valid possibility for 'singleton' beans within its context. Just because there are issues with some (very mainstream and hard to root out) implementations does not mean the Singleton pattern is always bad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hibernate won't get notified of changes made at the table level. The (bad) solution would be to update the data through Hibernate's API and to use one of the callback provided by an [Interceptor](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html_single/#objectstate-interceptors) to do some black magic voodoo with the Singleton. But honestly, the (right) way to handle this would be to get rid of that singleton and to put the data in 2nd level cache (and to invalidate the cache if you update the table manually).

(EDIT: As ChssPly76 mentioned in a comment, there is an intermediary solution if removing the singleton is not an option which consists in modifying the singleton to find and return cached hibernate-managed entities like your countries for example.)

Comment: +1 for 2nd level cache. OP doesn't even have to get rid of the singleton if it's tied into code; it should be trivial enough to refactor it to get stuff from the cache.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Implement [`Interceptor#onFlushDirty()`](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/Interceptor.html#onFlushDirty%28java.lang.Object,%20java.io.Serializable,%20java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.String[],%20org.hibernate.type.Type[]%29).</strike> Ah no, you want to do it from the other side on. No, it's not possible. Best what you can do is to reload the data at certain intervals, for example once every hour. You can use [`java.util.TimerTask`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) for this.

That said, a `Singleton` is really a bad idea. Just have it as some kind of an attribute of the main context. If it is for example an Java EE webapplication, you can use `ServletContext` for this.

Answer (score 1):

Your situation sounds ideal for the [L2 cache](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-cache) since your objects rarely change and set your expulsion policy accordingly to refresh. Further if **ALL** mods are done through Hibernate then you can keep track of what happens through the [events/interceptor](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/events.html) infrastructure. Of course, any auxiliary tables Hibernate does not know about would have to be tracked by other means like how @BalusC suggested.

Comment: +1 for cache; there's no need to mess with expiration or interceptors - it'll all happen auto-magically. For auxiliary tables (if there are any), the only reliable way is to have predefined entry points and manually notify all of possible changes; basically the same L2 cache but (if need be) distributed.

Comment: Kudos from @ChssPly76 on a Hibernate issue -- made my day right there :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that easiest approach to this is a [trigger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger) on the database end instead inside of your application. But this depends of course on the underlying database and if you really want to use SQL if everything else is done by Hibernate.

Comment: A trigger won't help to call a method on a singleton. I'm not sure what you have in mind.

Comment: A trigger can make a call to the app to reload the singleton.  i.e. place message on queue consumed by app, CORBA call to app, REST call etc.